# HLSL: Getting texture dimensions in a pixel shader

Tags: graphics, directx, hlsl, pixel-shader

I have a texture and I need to know its dimensions within a pixel shader. This seems like a job for [GetDimensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509693%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Here's the code:

```
Texture2D t: register(t4);
...
float w;
float h;
t.GetDimensions(w, h);
```

However, this results in an error:

> X4532: cannot map expression to pixel shader instruction set

This error doesn't seem to be documented anywhere. Am I using the function incorrectly? Is there a different technique that I should use?

I'm working in shader model 4.0 level 9_1, via DirectX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error usually occurs if a function is not available in the calling shader stage.

> Is there a different technique that I should use?

Use **shader constants** for texture width and height. It saves instructions in the shader, which may also be better performance-wise.

Comment: Thanks Lucius, I'm moving these out to a cbuffer. Good solution.